# Meteor android build version

Tags: meteor, meteoric

I have a strange issue. I build my Meteor app and run it on android device using -

```
meteor run android-device --mobile-server=<my_aws_ip>:3000
```

When the app deploys immediately it connects to the server (and my javascripts etc works). After a few seconds, the page refreshs and none of the javascript callbacks work. Please help me debug this issue.

More information: If I change the client (and not the server), and deploy it, for the first few seconds, the changed client gets shown on the phone. After the first few seconds, the version which is present on the server is shown. So I think Cordova or Meteor is trying to fetch the client code from the server, which is breaking the app. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Even more data points -

1. My aws code does NOT have android and ios platforms installed. Because of this, I think the cordova plugins are not installed, causing a JS break somewhere.
2. Easiest fix I can think of is remove cordova autoupdate. This is being added by meteor-platform package. If I clone meteor-platform and comment out the cordova autoupdate, the app doesn't load.

Is there another way of removing autoupdate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you have a different version of your app deployed at the `mobile-server` address.

The local code is run in **development mode**. Your AWS one is likely in production mode (and may contain a syntax error).

When you run your app it sees the code is different and fetches the new/old (different) version with a hot code reload - hence the page refresh/flash.

To fix this, you need to find the syntax error in your code. It's best to view the ADB logger or run with `meteor run --verbose android-device ....`

This will provide a bit more information such as an `Uncaught exception: cannot read .. of null` error type error.

It's hard to say what the error is. The error prevents the rest of your code from executing. In production mode the entire project is one JS file. If there is an error of any kind half way along the file, the rest of the file will not execute.

Also, try loading `<my_aws_ip>:3000` in your browser and watch for JS errors in the JS console.

You can also run it locally with `--production` to simulate a production build environment locally.

#### Enabling autoupdate but without a page refresh:

```
Reload._reload = function (options) {
    console.log("Next load will load new version");
};
```

Comment: Thanks @Akshat, appreciate the quick reply. However, I've written a follow up. Please let me know what you think.

Comment: @Akshay (my name without a t, haha?). You need the cordova platforms installed or it will auto update the wrong files.. If you run the project this way the remote server must have the same files and plugins as the local one..

Comment: (yea I know, coincidence with the names! :) ) so I've already implemented an alternate version of that Reload solution. Finally, is there a way to remove autoupdate altogether?